# Como 'inverter" gráfico do Google Charts?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tenho o seguinte gráfico que gero utilizando o Google charts:

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStacked);
function drawStacked() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['Ativo', 'Qtd. de erros'],
<?php
   $b = 0;
   while($b < 5){
   echo "['".$tabela['Papel'][$b].", ".$tabela['usuario'][$b]."',".$tabela['Tot_papel'][$b]."],";
   $b++;
   }
   ?>
]);
var options = {
title: 'Ranking qtd. de erros por ativos',
isStacked: true,
hAxis: {
title: 'Qtd de erros',
minValue: 0,
},
vAxis: {
title: 'Ativos'
}
};
var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

A `div` chamada :

```
<div id="chart_div" class="gogl" style="width: 600px; height: 300px"></div>
```

Tudo isso gera o seguinte gráfico:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As barras vão da esquerda para a direita, queria que o gráfico ficasse o espelho do que é agora, da direita pra esquerda.

Comment: Segundo API `vAxis.direction: '-1'` > https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart

Comment: Isso tá invertendo o gráfico na vertical, quero que inverta na Horizontal

Comment: Basta você indicar qual eixo você quer mudar a direção. `vAxis` (vertical), `hAxis` (horizontal). Acesse o link que postei ele explica certinho.

Comment: Aaaah consegui aqui, não tinha notado a diferença da primeira letra, agr melhorou, valeu cara :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta você atribuir `-1` a direção do eixo que você deseja inverter:

> **vAxis.direction** ou **hAxis.direction**
>
> Indica a direção na qual os valores ao longo do eixo crescem.
>
> Especifique -1 para inverter a ordem dos valores.
>
> **Valores aceitos: 1 ou -1**
>
> **Valor padrão: 1**
>
> [Google charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart)

Para inverter verticalmente:

```
vAxis.direction: '-1'
```

Para inverter horizontalmente:

```
hAxis.direction: '-1'
```

Comment: Perfeito, exatamente isso, Muito obrigado :D